# How to switch off an Android phone via USB signal?

Tags: android, button, usb

Is it possible to create a button that can connect to the android phone via  USB that when pressed switches off the phone immediately?

Comment: Edited from your original title: [*"Is it possible to create a red button that can connect to the android phone via usb and when pressed switches off the phone immediately?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32213141/1)  (Because everyone knows red buttons cannot be used to turn things off.  Red buttons only work for blowing things up--such as with self destruct switches.  Use a black or gray button instead.)

Answer (score 0):

if at the press of button you run this command it should do the trick

Try `adb shell reboot -p` to shutdown the phone.